# Returning the process.cwd() as the bash path to the directory instead of the cmd path?

Tags: windows, gruntjs, git-bash

How do I return the `process.cwd()` path for git-bash instead of the Windows cmd.exe path in grunt?

Comment: Please clarify more with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't return a 'nix path, unless it is running on 'nix.  Install upath and wrap it with a upath.normalize().

Ex: upath.normalize(process.cwd())

This should work on both 'nix and windows.